# import mysql data dump to Maria DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to import mysql data dump to Maria DB  with below command

```
mysql -u root -p --one-database new_db < data_dump.sql;
```

But I am getting below error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p --one-database zapcheck <
> zapcheck.sql' at line 1

I tried different combinations but nothing worked. Its not even telling what's the issue.

[image]

Please let me know the issue here or is there any other way I can import?

Comment: `mysql` is a shell command, you don't use it inside the `mysql` program.

Comment: @Barmar ahh I see.. now its showing the error if I run outside maria db. Where I am supposed to keep the dump file? Its not able to access it

Comment: @Barmar Or how can I specify the complete path?

Comment: What error is it showing now?

Comment: @Barmar getting this error `The system cannot find the file specified.`.
When I run `mysql -u root -p --one-database new_db < data_dump.sql;`

Comment: If you list the directory, do you see the `data_dump.sql` file?

Comment: What folder is the dump file in?

Comment: I am able to load with the commands yard mentioned. Thanks

Comment: In opened CLI interface you must use `SOURCE data_dump.sql` command. Previously you must make needed database current with USE command (and create it if it not exists) if this command is absent in the dump file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the command below to import the file:

> Note: Open the terminal where dump.sql is located

After opening the terminal:

```
//Skip this process if you have already created a database.
Mysql> create database newdb;

// Using the new created database
Mysql> use newdb;

// Importing the dump.sql file to newdb database
Mysql> source dump.sql
```

Comment: What is `zapcheck`?

Comment: Did you read the error message? The problem is that he's trying to run the command as a SQL query.

Comment: Getting this error while running second command -> `ERROR: Failed to open file 'zapcheck.sql', error: 2`.  File path is not proper I guess. Where I am supposed to keep the dump?

Comment: Now it worked after directing to correct path. Thanks